# The monotonicity of a function that is of complex form

Tags: calculus, analysis, monotone-functions

Consider the following function in $x\geq0$ with a parameter $q\in[0,1]$:

$f(x;q):=\frac{(1-e^{-x})^2}{e^{-x}(1+x)^2(1+qx-e^{qx}(1+x))^2}\bigg[(1+qx)^2+(2+qx)q^{2}x(1+x)^2+e^{qx}(1+x)\big\{(qx+1)(x-1)+q^{2}x(1+x)(qx(1+x)-2)\big\}\bigg]$

For a given $q\in[0,1]$, when I plot the function $f(x;q)$ in $x\geq0$, I can see that the function is monotonically (strictly) increasing in $x\geq0$, so I suspect that this monotonicity holds for $f(x;q)$ in general. I've tried to prove it by taking the first derivative, but as you can see, it is very complicated... I used the symbolic calculation/calculus in Mathematica, but it was not able to resolve the issue.

I am just wondering if there could be any way to prove that $f(x;q)$ increases in $x\geq0$ for a given $q\in[0,1]$. By the way, if $q=0$ or $q=1$, then the function $f(x;q)$ reduces to a quite simple form and I can easily show its monotonicity.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be really appreciated. Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

$f'(x) > 0$ for $x \ge 2$ and $q\in [0, 1]$:

---

**Proof**:

We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-x}}{(1 + x)^3[\mathrm{e}^{qx}(1 + x) - qx - 1]^3}
\Big[(f_1 \mathrm{e}^{2qx} + f_3 \mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_5)\mathrm{e}^x
+ f_2 \mathrm{e}^{2qx} + f_4 \mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_6\Big]$$
where
\begin{align*}
 f_1 &= -{q}^{4}{x}^{7}-5\,{q}^{4}{x}^{6}+{q}^{3}{x}^{7}-10\,{q}^{4}{x}^{5}+6
 \,{q}^{3}{x}^{6}-10\,{q}^{4}{x}^{4}+18\,{q}^{3}{x}^{5} -5\,{q}^{4}{x}^{
  3}\\
 &\quad +32\,{q}^{3}{x}^{4}-3\,{q}^{2}{x}^{5}-{q}^{4}{x}^{2}+33\,{q}^{3}{x}^
 {3}-8\,{q}^{2}{x}^{4}+q{x}^{5} +18\,{q}^{3}{x}^{2}-8\,{q}^{2}{x}^{3}\\
 &\quad +4
 \,{q}^{3}x-6\,{q}^{2}{x}^{2}+{x}^{4}-5\,{q}^{2}x+4\,q{x}^{2}-2\,{q}^{2
 }+3\,qx+4\,x+3, \\
    f_2 &= {q}^{4}{x}^{7}+5\,{q}^{4}{x}^{6}+{q}^{3}{x}^{7}+10\,{q}^{4}{x}^{5}+4\,
    {q}^{3}{x}^{6}+10\,{q}^{4}{x}^{4}+2\,{q}^{3}{x}^{5}+5\,{q}^{4}{x}^{3}\\
    &\quad -
    12\,{q}^{3}{x}^{4}-{q}^{2}{x}^{5}+{q}^{4}{x}^{2}-23\,{q}^{3}{x}^{3}-8
    \,{q}^{2}{x}^{4}+q{x}^{5}-16\,{q}^{3}{x}^{2}-16\,{q}^{2}{x}^{3}\\
    &\quad +4\,q{x
    }^{4}-4\,{q}^{3}x-10\,{q}^{2}{x}^{2}+{x}^{4}+{q}^{2}x-8\,q{x}^{2}+4\,{
     x}^{3}+2\,{q}^{2}-5\,qx-8\,x-5,\\
    f_3 &= -{q}^{5}{x}^{7}-4\,{q}^{5}{x}^{6}-{q}^{4}{x}^{7}-6\,{q}^{5}{x}^{5}-8\,
    {q}^{4}{x}^{6}-4\,{q}^{5}{x}^{4}-19\,{q}^{4}{x}^{5}-{q}^{5}{x}^{3}-19
    \,{q}^{4}{x}^{4}\\
    &\quad -6\,{q}^{3}{x}^{5}-8\,{q}^{4}{x}^{3}-22\,{q}^{3}{x}^{4
    }+{q}^{2}{x}^{5}-{q}^{4}{x}^{2}-30\,{q}^{3}{x}^{3}+7\,{q}^{2}{x}^{4}-
    18\,{q}^{3}{x}^{2}\\
    &\quad +10\,{q}^{2}{x}^{3}-2\,q{x}^{4}-4\,{q}^{3}x+13\,{q}^
    {2}{x}^{2}+13\,{q}^{2}x-6\,q{x}^{2}-{x}^{3}+4\,{q}^{2}-8\,qx-3\,x-4,\\
    f_4 &= {q}^{5}{x}^{7}+4\,{q}^{5}{x}^{6}-{q}^{4}{x}^{7}+6\,{q}^{5}{x}^{5}+4\,{
     q}^{5}{x}^{4}+7\,{q}^{4}{x}^{5}+{q}^{5}{x}^{3}+11\,{q}^{4}{x}^{4}+10\,
    {q}^{3}{x}^{5}\\
    &\quad +6\,{q}^{4}{x}^{3} +34\,{q}^{3}{x}^{4}+{q}^{2}{x}^{5}+{q}
    ^{4}{x}^{2}+42\,{q}^{3}{x}^{3}+13\,{q}^{2}{x}^{4}+22\,{q}^{3}{x}^{2}+
    32\,{q}^{2}{x}^{3}\\
    &\quad -2\,q{x}^{4}+4\,{q}^{3}x +19\,{q}^{2}{x}^{2}-5\,{q}^{
     2}x+18\,q{x}^{2}-{x}^{3}-4\,{q}^{2}+16\,qx+9\,x+8,\\
    f_5 &= -{q}^{4}{x}^{6}-3\,{q}^{4}{x}^{5}-3\,{q}^{4}{x}^{4}-3\,{q}^{3}{x}^{5}-
    {q}^{4}{x}^{3}-10\,{q}^{3}{x}^{4}-8\,{q}^{3}{x}^{3}-2\,{q}^{2}{x}^{4}-
    3\,{q}^{3}{x}^{2}\\
    &\quad -11\,{q}^{2}{x}^{3}-9\,{q}^{2}{x}^{2}-8\,{q}^{2}x-3\,
    q{x}^{2}-2\,{q}^{2}+3\,qx-x+1,\\
    f_6 &= -{q}^{4}{x}^{6}-3\,{q}^{4}{x}^{5}-3\,{q}^{4}{x}^{4}-3\,{q}^{3}{x}^{5}-
    {q}^{4}{x}^{3}-10\,{q}^{3}{x}^{4}-12\,{q}^{3}{x}^{3}-2\,{q}^{2}{x}^{4}
    -3\,{q}^{3}{x}^{2}\\
    &\quad -7\,{q}^{2}{x}^{3}-9\,{q}^{2}{x}^{2}+4\,{q}^{2}x-3\,
    q{x}^{2}+2\,{q}^{2}-9\,qx-x-3.
\end{align*}

We need the following auxiliary results (Facts 1-6).
I only give the proof of Fact 1 (at the end).
The other proofs are similar (using the substitutions $q = \frac{1}{1 + s}$ and $x = 2 + t$ for $s, t \ge 0$).

*Fact 1*: $f_1 > 0$ for all $q\in [0, 1]$
and $x\ge 2$.

*Fact 2*: $(1 + qx + q^2x^2/2)f_1 + f_3 > 0$ for all
$q\in [0, 1]$ and $x\ge 2$.

*Fact 3*: $[(1 + qx + q^2x^2/2)f_1 + f_3](1 + qx) + f_5 > 0$ for all
$q\in [0, 1]$ and $x\ge 2$.

*Fact 4*: $f_2 > 0$ for all $q\in [0, 1]$
and $x\ge 2$.

*Fact 5*: $(1 + qx)f_2 + f_4 > 0$ for all
$q\in [0, 1]$ and $x\ge 2$.

*Fact 6*: $[(1 + qx)f_2 + f_4](1 + qx) + f_6 > 0$ for all
$q\in [0, 1]$ and $x\ge 2$.

Using Facts 1-6, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(f_1 \mathrm{e}^{2qx} + f_3 \mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_5)\mathrm{e}^x
 + f_2 \mathrm{e}^{2qx} + f_4 \mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_6\\
 \ge\, & \Big[f_1 \mathrm{e}^{qx}(1 + qx + q^2x^2/2) + f_3 \mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_5\Big]\mathrm{e}^x
 + f_2 \mathrm{e}^{qx}(1 + qx) + f_4 \mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_6\\
 =\, & \Big(\Big[(1 + qx + q^2x^2/2)f_1 + f_3\Big]\mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_5\Big)\mathrm{e}^x
 + [(1 + qx)f_2 + f_4]\mathrm{e}^{qx} + f_6\\
 \ge\,& \Big(\Big[(1 + qx + q^2x^2/2)f_1 + f_3\Big](1 + qx) + f_5\Big)\mathrm{e}^x
 + [(1 + qx)f_2 + f_4](1 + qx) + f_6\\
 >\,& 0
\end{align*}
where we have used
$\mathrm{e}^{qx} \ge 1 + qx + q^2x^2/2$
and $\mathrm{e}^{qx} \ge 1 + qx$.

Thus, we have
$f'(x) > 0$ for all $q\in [0, 1]$ and $x\ge 2$.

We are done.

---

**Proof of Fact 1**:

If $q = 0$, we have $f_1 = x^4 + 4x + 3 > 0$.

If $q \in (0, 1]$, let $q = \frac{1}{1 + s}$ and $x = 2 + t$
for $s, t \ge 0$, we have
$$f_1 = \frac{(t + 3)^2}{(1 + s)^4}\cdot g_1$$
where
\begin{align*}
 g_1 &= s{t}^{5}+ \left( 14\,s+1 \right) {t}^{4}+ \left( {s}^{3}+78\,s+12
 \right) {t}^{3} + \left( {s}^{4}+8\,{s}^{3}-2\,{s}^{2}+216\,s+54
 \right) {t}^{2}\\
 &\quad + \left( 2\,{s}^{4}+15\,{s}^{3}-12\,{s}^{2}+299\,s+108
 \right) t+3\,{s}^{4}+18\,{s}^{3}+174\,s+81\\
 &> 0.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: +1. Impressive substitution and computation! Could you please share the intuition that led you to the substition? If the response is too long to fit in the comment section, would you please write it as the last part of your answer? Thank you.

Comment: @Hans Thanks. It is kind of transforming the range $[a, b)$ to $[0, \infty)$, for example, $x\in [2, 3)$, we may let $x = \frac{2 + 3s}{1 + s}$ for $s\ge 0$. It is also kind of the Buffalo Way.

Comment: Yes, I did know it was to transform $[0,1]$ to $[1,\infty]$ but was not sure why. Are these transformations to make all the independent variables the whole of the positive real axis?

Comment: @Hans Yes, we transform the range of a variable to $[0, \infty)$ because the optimal variable value is transformed to zero which is helpful sometimes. This is similar to the Buffalo Way.